# Javadoc multiline anchor tag

Tags: html, javadoc

I'd like to do something like this:

```
/**
 * Check out this <a href="#">external link</a>!.
 */
 public void foo() {

 }
```

However, the href for the external link is really long, like:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/this/is/a/really/long/link/and/it/doesnt/fit/on/one/line/which/is/problematic/with/javadoc">external link</a>
```

I'm conforming to a coding standard with a fixed line width.  Is there a way to format this with Javadoc?

Comment: One solution would be to use http://goo.gl or some other sort of shortening service.

Comment: Oh duh.  That's simple and obvious.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why don't you shorten it?

- http://bit.ly
- http://goo.gl

Just some right off the top of my head.

Comment: Not quite what the OP was asking about. Is there any way that the link can happen over multiple lines? I am curious as well.